# mysql is not reconised as an internal or external command

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm

I am installing mysql from the npm packages which installed fine but then ever I reference it for example

```
mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE node
```

It returns `mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I have done some research on google about it but its not explained very well.

Has anyone came across this problem before?

Comment: You have a problem with your path.

Comment: Sounds like it is not in your PATH. I'm assuming you using Linux? If so what distro? Type  `env | grep PATH` to see what is in your PATH.

Comment: Is your MySQL version 5.6 ? Is your MySQL service running?

Comment: The `mysql` module on npm has *nothing* to do with the mysql command line client.

Comment: Hi, I am just using my Windows 8 machine.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql NPM probably only contains mysql client bindings that connect to either a local, or remote mysql server that must be installed via the server environments package management system.

Ensure that the mysql server is installed and running on the system. Checking for this will be different depending on the distribution. Netstat would be one way:

```
sudo netstat -ntlp
```

Then look for 3306 and mysql. If it's not in the output you likely need to install mysql server on your system or perhaps it needs only to be started `systemctl start mysqld` or `service mysqld start` To install on a debian based system:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

You should then be able to create your databases with the command you referenced:

```
mysql -u root -e 'CREATE DATABASE node ...
```

Comment: If  you believe it is installed and running you probably just need to `source /etc/profile` or logout then back in to update your PATH. You could also use find to see if the mysql bin is on the system: `sudo find / -name "mysql*"`